# How to make one "if (variable = 100 || variable = 200)" etc better?

Tags: c#

I work with Windows Forms App in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, 
I have a function to show a `Messagebox.Show()` and update a level variable. The code is extremely ugly.

How can I do so it is infinite and not that ugly?

```
    void Level() //Levels.
    {
        if (count == 100 || count == 200 || count == 300 || count == 400 || count == 500 || count == 600 || count == 700 || count == 800 || count == 900 || count == 1000 ||
            count == 1100 || count == 1200 || count == 1300 || count == 1400 || count == 1500 || count == 1600 || count == 1700 || count == 1800 || count == 1900 || count == 2000 ||
                count == 2100 || count == 2200 || count == 2300 || count == 2400 || count == 2500 || count == 2600 || count == 2700 || count == 2800 || count == 2900 || count == 3000 ||
            count == 3100 || count == 3200 || count == 3300 || count == 3400 || count == 3500 || count == 3600 || count == 3700 || count == 3800 || count == 3900 || count == 4000)
        {
            level = level + 1;
            MessageBox.Show("Congratulations, you ranked up to level " + level.ToString(), "Cookie Clicker 2.0");
            label2.Text = "Level: " + level.ToString();

        }
        else if (count >= 4000)
        {
                    MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! We have not fixed any more in this game.",  "Cookie Clicker 2.0", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                       MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a set populated with those values and just ask if `count` is in the set. Take a look at `HashSet`.

Comment: store the values in an array and check array contains instead

Comment: Do you just want to check if count is divisible by 100? (count % 100 == 0)

Answer (score 5):

You can use C# [Modulo operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) as following:

```
void Level()
{
    if (count % 100 == 0 && count < 4000)
    {
        level = level + 1;
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations, you ranked up to level " + level.ToString(), "Cookie Clicker 2.0");
        label2.Text = "Level: " + level.ToString();
    }
    else if (count >= 4000)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! We have not fixed any more in this game.",  "Cookie Clicker 2.0", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Based on comment, it seems that count can go like 96,99,102.. so here is another solution (keep next level as separate variable):

```
private int _nextLevel = 100;
void Level()
{
    if (count > _nextLevel && count < 4000)
    {
        _nextLevel += 100;
        level = level + 1;
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations, you ranked up to level " + level.ToString(), "Cookie Clicker 2.0");
        label2.Text = "Level: " + level.ToString();
    }
    else if (count >= 4000)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! We have not fixed any more in this game.", "Cookie Clicker 2.0", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what does the % operator do?

Comment: In this case %-operator answers to question: "What is remainder when you divide count by number 100". If result is 0, count is divisible by 100. There is more info on link above.

Comment: I added it and tried it out, but. When if the value count is on 3 per click and it comes from 99 and jumps over 100 to 102 it don't update the level variable.

I are making a cookie clicker game, so I think you can find out how I think now.
How do I fix that?

Comment: I updated another solution which is suitable on that case. If it works, you can mark answer as accepted.

Comment: Uhm. Now I don't get the notification when I gets up to 100, not the level value updates either. Small gif; 
[HERE](https://gyazo.com/0e10ad2d969b70555edf5e5e4332bab8)

I can try to explain it more exactly.

When I click the "big cookie" it updates the "count" variable with "count" + "cookies", in this case "cookies" is one, so 0 + 1.

When you click the big button and comes to 100, it updates the "level" variable by one and shows a message, then if you hit 200 it gives another message and so, you understand?

Comment: Did you change your if to this: `if (count > _nextLevel && count < 4000)`? It works on my machine when I tested. Maybe you can share more code, your method which is calling this: Level()

Comment: When I click the mid button (button1) it trigger the functions.

        `private int level = 0;
        private int NextLevel = 100;
        private int count = 0;
        private int cookies = 1;`

`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Main button 
        {
            HowManyCookies();
            Level();
            LevelUpBackground();
        }`

To update the cookie text is this,

`void HowManyCookies() //Cookies.
        {
              count = count + cookies;
              label1.Text = "Cookies: " + count.ToString();
          }`

Comment: What does `LevelUpBackground()`?

Comment: It just sets a this.BackgroundImage to another if count value is on 100,250, and so.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

I don't see where you get the 'count' value, but you can do as follows, have this `List`

```
List<int> acceptedValues = new List<int>{ 100, 200, 300}; // add all the values you need

if (acceptedValues.Contains(count))
{
    level = level + 1;
    MessageBox.Show("Congratulations, you ranked up to level " + level.ToString(), "Cookie Clicker 2.0");
    label2.Text = "Level: " + level.ToString();

}
else if (count >= 4000)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! We have not fixed any more in this game.",  "Cookie Clicker 2.0", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
     MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
     MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
}
```

EDIT: If all your possible values are divisible by 100, Risto's answer way is better, though I would first check for `count >= 4000` and then `count % 100 == 0`